# Windows 8 / 8,.1 Desktop colour issue

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, colors

I seem to be having a major issue with Windows 8.1, which I think I had on Window 8 too.

Apps in Desktop mode have really bad colour issues.  The red is way over the top and the edge of skin colours goes horrible.  If I view an image in the Metro image viewer, then it looks correct, i.e. the same as on my camera, but the desktop Windows Photo Viewer and Lightroom 5 are both bad.

Photography and editing is one of my main hobbies, but at the moment I can't do anything with skin tones which is more than painful.

My graphics card is a AMD Radeon HD 2600 XT.  I've tried the latest driver, but it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: can you please post a picture of your issue?